# how to align flex applications to the left?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How can align my application to the left in Flex ?

The application is horizontally centered and when I resize the browser window it stays centered.
It is not css padding, it is flex padding, so I guess I have work with Flex code.

I've tried to add the following properties to the Application container: paddingLeft="0", left="0".. but it doesn't work. Still centered.

I've also tried to set "align","left" in the html/javascript code, but it doesn't solve the issue, because the padding is inside the flex application.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a root canvas in which your application content sits and set its left property to 0.

This will 'anchor' it to the left edge of your application window.

You can also do it in the designer:

[image: Anchor Left Example]